# Only render part of django template if objects.all is not empty

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I only want to render part of a django template if objects.all is not empty. Normally this is done like:

```
<ul>
{% for thing in things.all %}
    <li>{{ thing.name }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>Sorry, nothing to see here</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But what if I want to have a heading or something that only shows if there's something to put in the list? I don't want the heading to be repeated each time the for loop runs. Is there something like `{% not empty %}` I could use, e.g.:

```
{% if things.all not empty %}
<h1>Things</h1>
<ul>
{% for thing in things.all %}
    <li>{{ thing.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The above, however, throws a `TemplateSyntaxError` for django `Not expecting 'not' as infix operator in if tag.`

How can we check if something is empty *before* running the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. This check can be run by simply excluding the `not empty` clause:

```
{% if things.all %}
<h1>Things:</h1>
<ul>
{% for thing in things.all %}
    <li>{{ thing.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

No `TemplateSyntaxError`, and the `<h1>` is only printed once, before the loop, and only if there's something to list in the loop.